# ReactJS Passing Parent props while mapping an array of objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mapping

I am working on a component where I map over an array.  I need to pass a prop down through the mapping but I am struggling to do so because I cannot find a way to call the parent uuid as a mapping parameter

My array looks like this:

```
let location = {
    contact: { first_name: "Tom", last_name: "Tomson" },
    name: "Location One",
    uuid: 1111,
    departments: [
      {
        contact: { first_name: "James", last_name: "Potter" },
        name: "Department One",
        uuid: "AAA",
        subdepartments: [
          {
            contact: { first_name: "Lord", last_name: "Voldemort" },
            name: "Subdepartment Unit 1",
            uuid: "A1A1"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        name: "Food Department",
        uuid: "BBB",
        subdepartments: [
          {
            name: "Food Subdepartment Unit 1",
            uuid: "B1B1"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  };
```

What I want to do is map over the departments array and pass in the location.uuid as a property.

Here is my mapping function:

```
{location.departments.map((department, key, {location.uuid}) => {
   return (
     <div>
         <button
            id="department-tab-button"
            name={department.name}
         >
         {location.uuid}
         </ button >
         {department.subdepartments.map((subdepartment, key, {department.uuid}) => {
             return (
                <button>
                   {department.uuid}
                </button>
             )
         })}
    })}
```

My issue is I cannot pass department.uuid through the mapped function.  I want the subdepartment button to display the uuid of the department that is its parent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you already did. Its just that your syntax is not correct.

```
return location.departments.map((department) => (
  <div>
    <button id="department-tab-button" name={department.name}>
      {location.uuid}
    </button>
    {department.subdepartments.map(() => <button>{department.uuid}</button>)}
  </div>
));
```

Comment: @dev_jumwen Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

**Have you ever read about [Map operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)?**

Map operator receive three parameters:

```
array.map(function(currentValue, index, arr), thisValue)
```

```
{department.subdepartments.map((subdepartment, index, array) => {
     // subdepartment here is an item in department.subdepartments
     // index here is index of subdepartment inside department.subdepartments
     // array here is department.subdepartments
     // so, if you define {department.uuid} instead array here, it is wrong
     return (
         <button>
             {department.uuid}
         </button>
     )
})}
```

So, in your case, should be:

```
{location.departments.map((department, index, arr) => {
   return (
     <div>
         <button
            id="department-tab-button"
            name={department.name}
         >
         {location.uuid}
         </ button >
         {department.subdepartments.map(() => {
             return (
                <button>
                   {department.uuid}
                </button>
            )
        })}
    </div>
})}
```